# Ubuntu 14.04 Brightness keeps going to 100%

Tags: 14.04, brightness, preferences

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 for the first time. Although I have set brightness a million times, every time I start the computer, it goes to maximum again. If I restart the computer it remembers my brightness definitions, but I completely turn off, it forgets.

How can I get it to remember my preferences?

Thank you, cheers.